# Cronjob in background

Tags: linux, bash, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I have a bash script already tested and working fine. It's a listener that trigger a command on new created files in a specific directory. I added it in crontab "* *     * * *   root   /bin/bash /var/permission.sh". The problem I faced is that this script is always running and every minute a new process is added without killing the previous one so I ended up with high number of processes on the server.
Is there a way to kill the previous process when new one is added?

Comment: Why doesn't `/var/permission.sh` terminate itself after doing its job? Or if it's always active, why keep rescheduling it? If there are good reasons for working this way, then `pidof` and `killall` allow access to running programs by name.

Comment: because I need it always running, now I am using a command to kill all process sudo pkill -f /var/lpermission.sh but I am asking if there's something automated or timeout.

Comment: If it's always running, why would you need to kill and restart it every minute?

Comment: yes as i mentioned before it's always running but here how it works:
proc 1 executed ---> 1 min later proc 2 executed ---> 1 min later proc 3 executed
these all procs are related to my cronjob so I have 3 procs all related to one exact cronjob. So here I am asking If it works like this is there a way to kill proc 1 when 2 started and kill proc 2 when 3 started and so on

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just keep the first one running, and not start a new one every minute? You could make your script write its pid in a file, and the next one could then check that -- and either kill the previous one, or just terminate itself...

Comment: I will run the script in a tmux session, this must work! Thanks

Comment: This question reads very much like an [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: tmux is a good alternative for making a process running in the background, the cronjob was working fine but the problem is just in adding a new process each time.